# Show that $\text{Hom}(eR,-)$ and $-e$ are naturally isomorphic functors

Tags: ring-theory

Good Morning everyone. I'm currently having trouble with the following:

**Problem:**

Show that, if $e$ is an idempotent element of a ring $R$, then the two functors $$\text{Hom}(eR,-):\textbf{Mod-R}\to\textbf{Ab},$$ and $$-e:\textbf{Mod-R}\to\textbf{Ab},$$ where $-e$ is defined on the objects as $N_R\mapsto Ne$, are canonically isomorphic.

**Attempt:**

Since the text asks to find a canonical isomoprhism, my guess was to define a map $$\eta_N:\textbf{Ab}\to\textbf{Ab}$$ as follows:

$\eta_N(f)(er)=f(er)e\quad \forall f\in\text{Hom}(eR,N_R)$. But then i have to prove that $\eta_N$ is an isomorphism for any right $R-$module $N_R$ and at this point I'm stuck.

Moreover i've tried to write $f(er)e=f(e)re$ because i thought i am working with right $R-$modules morphism, but even at this point i'm not sure how to go ahead.

Any solution or hint will be appreceiated and rewarded. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural transformation is a collection of maps
$$\eta_N:\text{Hom}(eR,N)\to Ne$$
for each object $N$ in Mod-R, satisfying the naturality condition.

Define $\eta_N(f)$ as the element $f(e)$ of $Ne$, and note that the inverse $\eta_N^{-1}(n)$ is the element $r\mapsto nr$ of $\text{Hom}(eR,N)$. You can check that this is an isomorphism, and technically you should also check that this is natural in $N$.

edit:

To check naturality, for all morphisms $\phi:N\to M$ in Mod-R there are induced morphisms $\phi e:Ne\to\ Me$ (which is just a restriction of $\phi$) and $\text{Hom}(eR,\phi) : \text{Hom}(eR,N) \to \text{Hom}(eR,M) $ (postcomposition by $\phi$). The naturality condition we wish to check is $(\phi e) \circ \eta_N=\eta_M \circ \text{Hom}(eR,\phi)$. Unwrapping this a bit more, we are checking that $\phi(\eta_N(f))=\eta_M(\phi\circ f)$, which with the above $\eta$ becomes just $\phi(f(e))=(\phi\circ f)(e)$.

Comment: how to check this is natural?

Comment: I've added a paragraph about [naturality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation).